# How to use an enum field in annotations in java

Tags: java, enums, static, annotations

I have my own ErrorMessages enum, simply:

```
public enum ErrorMessages {
  NO_USER(1004, "User not found"),
  UNKNOWN_MODULE(1006, "Module unknown"),
  INCORRECT_DATE(1009, "Incorrect date");

  public final int code;
  private final String messageEng;

  ErrorMessages(int code, String messageEng) {
    this.code = code;
    this.messageEng = messageEng;
  }

  public int getCode() {
    return code;
  }

  public String getMessageEng() {
    return messageEng;
  }
}
```

And want to pass the error code to my json-rpc api method as follows:

```
@JsonRpcMethod("MyMethod")
  @JsonRpcErrors(@JsonRpcError(exception = UserNotFoundException.class, code = ErrorMessages.NO_USER.getCode()))
  boolean myMethod(
      @JsonRpcParam("userId") Integer userId, @JsonRpcParam("apiKey") String apiKey)
      throws UserNotFoundException;
```

But I get error `Attribute value must be constant`.
I know that values should be passed to annotations on compile time, but i thought it is already known in my case.
Is there any way to pass the error's code there by getting from ErrorMessages enum? It would be quite stupid to hardcode the code numbers, having them already declared.

I've tried to apply some suggestions from threads in sof i found but failed. There was one way to rewrite enum to an interface, but i'd like to avoide it

Answer (score 1):

The compiler doesn't know that the value in your enum is a constant. However, there's a workaround: You can make the enum value a constant itself:

```
public enum ErrorMessages {
  NO_USER(NO_USER_CODE, "User not found"),
  // etc
  ;

  public static final int NO_USER_CODE = 1004;
  // etc
}
```

Then refer to the constant in your annotation:

```
  @JsonRpcErrors(@JsonRpcError(exception = UserNotFoundException.class, code = ErrorMessages.NO_USER_CODE))
```

If you have control over the annotation, you could pass the enum itself instead, and do the code/message lookup at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

You can move the int codes to a separate class:

```
public static class ErrorMessagesValues {
    public static final int NO_USER_CODE = 1004;
    public static final int UNKNOWN_MODULE_CODE = 1006;
    public static final int INCORRECT_DATE_CODE = 1009;
}
```

then refer to those constants in both the enum:

```
public enum ErrorMessages {
    NO_USER(ErrorMessagesValues.NO_USER_CODE, "User not found"),
    UNKNOWN_MODULE(ErrorMessagesValues.UNKNOWN_MODULE_CODE, "Module unknown"),
    INCORRECT_DATE(ErrorMessagesValues.INCORRECT_DATE_CODE, "Incorrect date");

    ...
}
```

and the annotation:

```
@JsonRpcMethod("MyMethod")
@JsonRpcErrors(@JsonRpcError(exception = UserNotFoundException.class, code = ErrorMessagesValues.NO_USER_CODE))
```